# Cannot write result of batch file processing using DOS START command

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, dos

I have a batch file which will run multiple programs using DOS start command. However, I could not write the programs' result to their respective text file.

```
start program1.exe > result1.txt
start program2.exe > result2.txt
```

If my batch file is simply

```
program1.exe > result1.txt
```

Then the result can be written to result1.txt

Is there a problem in my syntax? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, if you type "start winword.exe > result.log" nothing is written in the log. It's usual.

Comment: program1.exe is a program which will print the results onto the console, and I am using the redirection operator to write the results to a file

Comment: Some programs doesn't write its output to STDOUT, they write to STDERR or other Streams (eg. java.exe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the programs write to stdout, you can get the output of the command called by Start by using a separate CMD and escaping the redirection operator

Try this:

```
start "" CMD /C program1.exe^>result1.txt
start "" CMD /C program2.exe^>result2.txt
```

Ex:

```
c:\Scripts\Batch>start "" CMD /C ping -n 1 localhost>testping1.txt

c:\Scripts\Batch>type testping1.txt
            *Nothing comes up because the file is empty*
c:\Scripts\Batch>start "" CMD /C ping -n 1 localhost^>testping1.txt

c:\Scripts\Batch>type testping1.txt

Pinging YourComputer [::1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ::1: time<1ms

Ping statistics for ::1:
Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Comment: start "" CMD /C "program1.exe>result1.txt" <--- that should work too.